# Classification: how important is the sample-to-feature ratio?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

Some people mention you should have at least 5 times as many samples as features for classification problems [1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12912828). I've also heard people on here saying the sample-to-feature ratio is arbitrary and unimportant $^{[citation\ needed]}$.

**Is there a general rule of thumb for the sample-to-feature ratio when classifying?** What happens if you violate it?

[[1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12912828)] Somorjai, Ray L., B. Dolenko, and Richard Baumgartner. "Class prediction and discovery using gene microarray and proteomics mass spectroscopy data: curses, caveats, cautions." Bioinformatics 19.12 (2003): 1484-1491.

Comment: The link does not work for me.  Please add a citation to the paper!

Comment: @MatthewDrury Thanks for noticing. The link is fixed!

Comment: One note to make, it looks like that paper makes recommendations within the context of a very specific type of classification problem.  I wouldn't take a domain dependent rule of thumb to be a general recommendation that applies to *all* classification problems.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I'm confused if there's a general rule of thumb at all. I've both heard recommendations like in the paper ("need some ratio of samples to features") and recommendations that the ratio isn't important. What makes the ratio important or not? The paper says that a low SF ratio leads to high accuracy but poor interpretability. Is this a general rule? Is it always case by case? What makes the cases differ?? Happy to revise the original question to reflect this.

Comment: ... For example, I've seen people worried about having more features than samples, but I've also heard of successful classifications with tens of thousands of features and only dozens of samples. That confuses me! (I don't have examples on hand, but I'll try and find them if needed.)

Comment: This is kind of why there is no rule of thumb.  When you are using techniques like regularization, the concept of "number of features" gets pretty murky.  Most applications of n_features > n_samples lean heavily on variance reduction strategies like regularization.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Thanks. Is it correct to say that variance reduction turns problems with n_features>>n_samples into problems with n_features~=n_samples, i.e. reduces the number of features before classifying? Is it that simple? Also, are you able to point to something that'd help me understand exactly what a variance reduction strategy is (e.g. regularization)?

Comment: That's kind of true, if you interpret everything in exactly the correct way.  This paper was helpful in sorting out these concepts for me: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/df_paper_LJrev6.pdf